# Apache Flink DataSet difference/subtraction operation

Tags: apache-flink

I'm currently trying to implement some algorithms in both, Apache Spark and Apache Flink. When executing the algorithms, I have to do some kind of set difference/subtraction operations.

While there is a built-in `subtract` operation for Apache Spark, I couldn't find something similar in Apache Flink (1.0.3 and 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT).

So my question is, given two DataSet objects `d1, d2` both containing the same type `T`, what is the most efficient way to apply set difference, i.e. `d1\d2`?

```
val d1: DataSet[T] = ...
val d2: DataSet[T] = ...
val d_diff: DataSet[T] = ???
```

Probably there is some way to it via `coGroup`

```
val d_diff = d1.coGroup(d2).where(0).equalTo(0) {
               (l, r, out: Collector[T]) => {
                val rightElements = r.toSet
                for (el <- l)
                  if (!rightElements.contains(el)) out.collect(el)
               }
             }
```

but I'm wondering whether that's the correct way or even best-practice or does anybody know some more efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DataSet API does not provide methods for it as it only contains the very basic set of operations. The Table API in 1.1 will have a set minus operator. You can see how it is implemented [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-libraries/flink-table/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/api/table/plan/nodes/dataset/DataSetMinus.scala).

```
  leftDataSet
    .coGroup(rightDataSet)
    .where("*")
    .equalTo("*")
    .`with`(coGroupFunction)
```

Using [this CoGroupFunction](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-libraries/flink-table/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/api/table/runtime/MinusCoGroupFunction.scala). So yes, you are on the right track.